# White X on battery icon of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, battery

I just bought a Lenovo laptop and installed Windows 10 and everything looks fine but I see a cross inside the battery icon:

[image]

What is the problem? Is the battery damaged?

EDIT: I just started to install Windows 10 in another same laptop(I have bought 5 of them) and I see the same icon in other one too!

The laptop model is Lenovo ideapad H330.

Comment: What does it say when you hover your mouse pointer over the icon, or when you click on it?

Comment: @StarCat: It says its charging(1hr and x minutest until fully charged).

Comment: what model laptop?

Comment: @Keltari: I edited my post.

Comment: @Keltari: I edited my post.

Comment: @StarCat are you sure thats the model?  According to Lenovo the H330 is a desktop.  There is an ideapad 330, no H

Comment: Does the laptop work when not connected to AC power? It may simply be a display bug in Windows 10, perhaps related to the 255% bug.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Do the batteries eventually fully charge and is the white cross still there? @Keltari, I assume you're refering to user145959's original question and not to my comment?

Comment: Run Lenovo System Update (Lenovo Support Site) and update all drivers including Power Management, Power Driver, BIOS and Chipset. Do that and restart before drawing any conclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did a fresh install of Windows 10, I assume you are just missing some software or driver for power management or battery control.

Go to the Lenovo support website and download all the appropriate drivers and software for your laptop make, model, and operating system.

There seems to be some confusion on your model, but this *might* be the appropriate [page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-u-series-laptops/ideapad-u330/downloads/driver-list/).  There is power management software in this list. 
 If not, fine to the proper model on the site and download the correct software.

Comment: Power management in PCs is highly standardized (ACPI). I don’t think additional software is required.

Comment: @DanielB maybe.  maybe not.  there is custom "power management" software, as well as other software.  It certainly wouldnt hurt to intstall Lenovo software specific to that model to see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Thank you Keltari. After I restarted the computers it updated the Windows automatically and the problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it may be because you are using a weak charger. So during the updates installation the charger didn't have enough power to charge your laptop. I have the same issue now, Dell Precision running on 65W dock station (Precision needs at least 130W)